# How to resize table of buttons to work fine with all phones

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

Hello i'am trying to make a Tictactoy game my problem is in the layout design how to make it when the screen grows bigger the table and buttons inside become grow bigger and When the screen is smaller, the table and buttons inside become smaller not only the table

There is any way to fix this ?

[The Correct one(my sccren)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rsl7.png)

[The wrong one(when i change it to a smaller sccren)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s27Sf.png)

,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.pc.tictactoyv1.act11">


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/Table"
    android:layout_width="357dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.42"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.356">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn3"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn5"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn6"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:onClick="SelectBtn"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: could you show what code you got so far?

Comment: i finshed the cod the only problem in the design

Comment: If you finished the code then what are you asking here?

Comment: i have problem with the layout

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- `ConstraintLayout` with percentage guidelines
- nested vertical and horizontal `LinearLayouts` with weights
- creating a `CustomView` that handles the sizes in `onMeasure`
- `ImageViews` with white rectangular background, set to `fitXY` and `adjustViewBounds = true`

These are just some options I came up with at the top of my head, there are many more. Pick whatever suits your needs best. For beginners probably the way with the `ConstraintLayout` is the easiest.

I still don't exactly know what you want, but I added an example, that scales evenly, using `ConstraintLayout` and chains. Also checkout the `constraintDimensionRatio` whick makes everything square. You might want to checkout [Constraint Layout How To](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Btn9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Btn5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:onClick="SelectBtn"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Btn6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you check the cod and tell me which one should i do

Comment: You did not copy the whole layout, I can not replicate the pictures.